# How to get GStreamer for Windows and for Android work together with h264 over RTP?

Tags: android, windows, h.264, gstreamer

My goal is to capture video, encode it with x264, stream it over RTP, receive it on Android, decode and display with as low latency as possible to get.
The encoder/sender machine is Windows 7 with OSS build "GStreamer-WinBuilds-GPL-x86-Beta04-0.10.7.msi" installed (released on 03.2011). It happily runs the capture/encode/stream pipline that looks like this:

gst-launch.exe -v ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240, framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5400

I have tested the stream with a client pipeline running on the same machine:

gst-launch.exe udpsrc port=5400 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! gstrtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale ! "video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240" ! autovideosink

And it plays really well.

I have successfully built an Android application based of GStreamer and it is possible for me to build custom pipilenes and run them on Android. But when I stream to my phones IP and run the same receiver pipeline on Android I get unwatchable crippled video of very low quality, with blocks and artifacts all over the picture.

The GStreamer SDK version for Android is: http://cdn.gstreamer.com/android/arm/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2012.11.zip 
It looks like it's a newer build.

So I decided to install the same build version of GStreamer SDK on my Windows 7 machine also: http://cdn.gstreamer.com/windows/x86-64/gstreamer-sdk-x86_64-2012.11.msi

Now when I run sender pipline on Windows with older OSS build and receiver pipeline with newer SDK build I get the same effect as on Android: the video is displayed but it is broken.
I cannot test it on windows with the newer SDK as sender, because the new SDK does not include any encoders and it is not clear to me how to add any.

So the question is: how do I get the same version of GStreamer running on Windows as encoder and on Android as receiver?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried update to SDK 2013.6? Seems it fixes some bugs.